# problem upgrading php

Tags: wordpress, php, upgrade

I updated to CiviCRM 4.7.28 (on Wordpress). However, I have not been able to update the PHP to the 5.6 version. In fact, after much searching, I don't seem to be able to come up with the correct way to update the PHP. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to contact your host to check that php 5.6 is available.  It very likely is in which case there is probably a facility in your cpanel or equivalent to activate this.  I recently upgraded my setup to php7 on wordpress without any problems and in fact things are working quite a bit faster.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for the tip. It worked! So easy when you know how!